# My program runs from Esclipse, but not from terminal, citing that a file does not exist (but it does)

Tags: python, file-io

So I have this code to open the file "setup.json", and it works fine when i run the program from eclipse but when I run it from terminal on my Mac I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'setup.json'
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
file = "setup.json"
for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if f == file:
        file = f 
with open(file,"r") as fi:
    #(other code, irrelevant because the program crashes before this point
```

`setup.json` is in a folder `HueSunset` with two other files, "`\__init__.py`" and `\__main__.py`. `\__main__.py` is the file that this code is running from.

Comment: Check the file permissions and make sure your script can access the file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "works in my IDE" isn't pertinent.

Comment: @duffymo I think it is relevant because it shows that it works and that the code is fine, the problem is whatever difference occurs when running it from terminal instead.

Comment: @suraj thanks, will do this in the future

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your `for` loop is unnecessary and redundant. It assigns to the name `file` only if `f` is already set to the value of `file`. It basically does `if file == file: file=file`.

Comment: No, it shows that you're too dependent on the IDE to do things that you don't understand.  Yes, it should work in the IDE, but you don't deploy or run in an IDE.  It's not "fine".

Comment: @That1Guy yeah, I noticed that a couple minutes ago. Silly me.

Comment: @duffymo which is precisely why I'm trying to learn what my issue is when I run it out of the IDE.

Comment: I'm sure your issue has to do with paths.  Your IDE knows how to find that .json file, but you've done nothing to tell Python how to find it when you're not in the IDE.  That's precisely my point.

Comment: @duffymo in my efforts to try and solve this issue I removed the redundant part and made `file = os.getcwd()+"/setup.json"`, which should point directly to the file. Also, this site is for help and learning, not for you to tell me about my lack of knowledge in the area.

Comment: Pointing out your over-dependence on your IDE is a form of help and learning.  Pointing out that the path is the issue is helping.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the cases I could come up with:

1. Clear the IDEs cache and re-run
2. Make sure you do not have another file with the same name
3. Check for files permission
4. At the last you can run your code on online editor to make sure the code you are running is correct. If yes, then it is the problem of your file and location.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 1) I couldnt for the life of me figure out how to do this, 2) Dont have another file with the same name 3) I unlocked all the files so there should be no problems here 4) I did this as well and the code ran fine after i added the file to the online editor. My file location is being referenced correctly I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will leave `file` unchanged if it does not find it in the current directory. The current directory is the directory you are in when you execute the script.

Try this:

```
file = "setup.json"
for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if f == file:
        break
else:
    print("Oops. File not found") # or in real production code, raise an exception
with open(f,"r") as fi:
    #rest of your code
```